# Jquery combobox set selected value

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, combobox

My code is the following:

**View**

```
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Employee.ManagerId)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Employee.ManagerId, Model.Employee.ManagerList, new { @placeholder = "Select a Manager...", @disabled = "true" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Employee.ManagerId)
```

**View (Jquery Code)**

This functions calls the controller in order to get the list that will be filled in ManagerList.

```
function RefreshManagers(engineerSelected) {
    if (engineerSelected != "") {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("ReloadManagersByEmployee", "Locator")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { employeeId: engineerSelected },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#Employee_ManagerId").empty();
                $.each(data.managers, function (index, optiondata) {
                    $(document.createElement('option'))
                        .attr('value', optiondata.Value)
                        .text(optiondata.Text)
                        .appendTo($("#Employee_ManagerId"));
                });
                $("#Employee_ManagerId").combobox("refresh");
            },
            error: function (xhr) { alert("Unable to reload managers"); }
        });
    }
    else {
        $("#Employee_ManagerId").empty();
        $("#Employee_ManagerId").append("<option value=''>Select a Manager...</option>");
    }
    $("#Employee_ManagerId").combobox("refresh");
}
```

**Controller:**
The controller returns the following:

```
public JsonResult ReloadManagersByEmployee(string employeeId)
    {
        //Do the stuff...call the corresponding service and get the list, then:
        return Json(new
        {
            managers = managerList
        });
    }
```

Note: When creating the list 'managerList' I have already pre-selected the value that I want to show.

**Problem:**

The selected manager (previously selected when creating the list) is not correctly set when JQuery creates the combobox.

I have checked the list just before returning it to the view and is correctly set.

**Question:**

Once the *RefreshManagers()* function loads the manager list, how can I do to change the selected value of that list to the one already selected in the controller?

**Question 2:**

The Manager list is refreshed correctly by applying the change that @Stephen Muecke told but when passing the model to the controller, the manager id selected is not passed (is null always)

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Employee.ManagerId, Model.Employee.ManagerList, new { @placeholder = "Select a Manager..." })
```

**Why this property is not passed correctly?**

**Answer**

It didn't pass the value because in the DropDownListFor was set the property @disabled = true, just put it to false.

Comment: How have you _"selected one in the controller"_? (nothing in your code shows you selecting a value). You set the selected item using `$("#Employee_ManagerId").val(someValue);`

Comment: Best guess is your returning `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` which is unnecessary since you just send a whole lot of extra data to the view which you don't use (the client has no concept of a c# class). Just send a collection of anonymous objects and an additional value for the selected value e.g. - `var data = yourQuery.Select(x => new {Value = x.ID, Text = x.Name }; return Json( new { managers = data, selectedValue = someValue });`

Comment: @StephenMuecke You are super right =D Thank you! (I thought that only selecting the value when creating the list was enough...but not..)